# Jquery/PHP: Javascript function fails to run

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

excuse my poor titling skills. I wish to run a simple javascript function that for now only returns an echo from a php page. I have linked to the function and it gets to the function but fails to complete. I don't think i have anything noticeably wrong with the code but nothing happens.

Javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PopulateBoxes(){
        $.post('PopulateBoxes.php', {date: SelectTourForm.lst_MonthDrop.value },
            function(output){
                $('#txt_Duration').hmtl(output).show();
            }
        ); 
    }
</script>
```

PopulateBoxes.php:

```
<?php
    echo "This is a test";
?>
```

The drop down menu:

```
<form id="SelectTourForm" style="margin:5px;">
    <table border="0" align="center" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label style="color:#FFF; font:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:20px; margin-left:10px; margin-top:25px">Select Tours Details</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="lst_MonthDrop" style="background-color:#FF9933; color:#FFF; border:none; margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;" onchange="PopulateBoxes();">
                    <option>Please Select</option>
                    <?php 
                    include 'populatedrodown.php';
                    foreach ( $results as $option ) :
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $option->Date; ?>"><?php echo $option->Date; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" name="btn_TourSearch" id="btn_TourSearch" value="Search" style="background:#009300; border-radius:5px; border-color:#009300; color:#FFF;margin-left:5px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does firebug/javascript console show?

Comment: What is executing `PopulateBoxes`, and where is `PopulateBoxes` defined?

Comment: html is misspelled as hmtl

Comment: @peterchon Thanks for that but unfortunately, it didn't fix the problem I'm having. But it does help.

Comment: Where is SelectTourForm.lst_MonthDrop ?

Comment: @KevinB The function PopulateBoxes is called on an onchange of a drop down menu. I have tested this using an alert and it displays that message. However the function doesn't run.

Comment: If you `alert(SelectTourForm.lst_MonthDrop.value)` before `$.post`, does it give you the expected value?

Comment: Have you tried manually posting to the php file? What is `$('#txt_Duration')` supposed to be selecting?

Comment: I was hope that once i got the function to link to the php page properly i would select data from the db to populate the text field 'txt_Duration'

Comment: what does `alert($('#txt_Duration').length)` give you?

Comment: It somehow give the value 1?? I don't know why though.

Comment: what happens if you run it without the {date: SelectTourForm.lst_MonthDrop.value }? does it return "this is a test"?

Comment: @user2966161 1 is the expected value, since there can be only one of that element on the page.

Comment: I just tested  $.post('PopulateBoxes.php', function(output){  $('#txt_Duration').html(output).show();
   });                        and the output was still nothing.

Comment: Is there and alternative way to select from a db without refreshing the original page that is perhaps slightly easier?

Comment: Nope, unless you want to use iframes, though i wouldn't consider that easier.

Comment: Ok looks like it's gonna be a long night.

Answer (score 0):

Your error was at SelectTourForm.lst_MonthDrop.value, used as is, JavaScript does not recognized it.

I tested this for your reference and worked:
As lst_MonthDrop only has name, having no id, we get its value by:

```
$("select[name=lst_MonthDrop]").val()
```

Here is the test structure:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function PopulateBoxes(){
 $.post('PopulateBoxes.php',
   {date: $("select[name=lst_MonthDrop]").val()},
   function(output){
     $('#txt_Duration').html(output).show();
   }); 

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // just for test
  PopulateBoxes();

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="txt_Duration"></div>
<?php
// your form here...
?>    

</body>
</html>
```

I got this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `SelectTourForm.lst_MonthDrop.value` is defined if you have a form with an id of `SelectTourForm` that contains a form control that has an id of `lst_MonthDrop`

Comment: @Kevin B, i've updated my answer that is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

problems:

**1:** `hmtl` should be `html`

**2:** `SelectTourForm.lst_MonthDrop.value` should be $("select[name=lst_MonthDrop]").val()

**3:** There is no element with id `txt_Duration` in your shown html. Create it.

**4:** `populatedrodown.php` is likely to be misspelled. Missing a letter `p`?

Comment: I have corrected number 1, Number 2. Number 3 is created but in another form on the same page(Hope that didn't affect it), I know I misspelled drop but i ensured it was the correct spelling everywhere else by copy and paste.

Comment: @Seatter Are you sure you are including jquery in your `<head>`? `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>`

Comment: Tip: Always use the browser's element inspector and the `Net` tab of it to see what data is being sent and received.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> thats the js file i used in my <head>.